# Google places API- place type. How can I customize this?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got this 1 line code from developers.google.com.

Can anyone explain to me what does the code means. and can I replace museum with hospitals under the types part, since im developing an app that navigates to hospitals

" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json? 
   location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=museum&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere"

Comment: you can use as **type=hospital**

Comment: What questions do you have on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. list of supported place types

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

*types — Restricts the results to places matching at least one of the specified types. Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (type1|type2|etc)*

Check this https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: hello bro. thanks for the info. but cn i simply replace the museum wit hospitals, or is there some other way to limit my search

Comment: If you have api key try replacing the place type and check. For more customization you should refer the API doc(I have added that link also)

Answer (score 0):

This Code Needs API_KEY to be access this line...

it Contains Following Parts

> **location=51.503186,-0.126446** - Latitude and Longitude, means a place from where it starts searching
>
> **radius=5000** - "radius" localizes results to a certain radius.
>
> **types=museum** - Restricts the results to places matching at least one of the specified types (You can change it to "hospital")
>
> **key=AddYourOwnKeyHere** - Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management and so that places added from your application are made immediately available to your app

Follow This Document For More Info... [**Place Search**](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)